# Bug in badges? 5/5 - next badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed on my Stack Overflow account today that the 'curious' badge has 5/5, yet remains in my 'next badge' section:

[image]

Very strange... Also, just to show I haven't received it:

[image]

What's happening?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a postive question record.

If you click on the badge, it will show this.

[image]

Comment: I noticed this, I'm trying to find a proper definition of 'positive question record', but judging by my question history I can't think why I wouldn't have one

Comment: @gdgr Then the question I linked to above, provides the answer.

Comment: Found the definition via the question you linked.. thank you. I guess I just don't meet it! :(

Comment: @gdgr You undoubtedly have deleted downvoted questions, they still count for the purposes of this badge.

Comment: Of your 13 questions, 6 have positive score and 7 don't. You also have the peer pressure badge, which suggests you've got a downvoted deleted post, usually a question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I try my best with SO but it's somewhat a learning curve and difficult to keep track of all the facets of the system. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gdgr it seems like you're on the right track, though. not far off and none of your current questions are obviously terrible. gl.

Comment: @TZHX, thank you! As I say I do try, lately I've been trying to give back more by way of answering questions. It's a great place and a valuable community